# Play store on AVD

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator

Is it possible to install the play store and download apps on an AVD (Android Virtual Device, aka Emulator)? I can't seem to find an image or anything documents on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion emulator, it allows you to install applications from Google Play.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354713/install-an-app-from-google-play-on-emulator) for more solutions.